# Magento, CSS not rendering correctly on IE8

Tags: php, css, magento, internet-explorer-8

I am new to magento,

I have a project in Magento but Its layout is breaking in IE8,

I tried

```
 <!--[if IE 8]>
      .category-grid .item { 
           display:inline-block !important; 
      }
 <![endif]-->
```

these codes in css file but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block will not work in IE8 if you dont have `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` before your HTML tag.

Comment: magento provides the doctype declaration by default. there is no need to alter it.

Comment: @ArunWilson check my answer below. you forgot `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles should be written in `<style>` tag. like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <style>
      .category-grid .item { 
          display:inline-block !important; 
      }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```